# Named router outlet not rendering same component after refreshing

Tags: angular

I am using named router outlet in angular 7 and the corresponding component is rendering see below code.

```
 this.router.navigate(['./globalassetmanager/main/assets/assetfamilies'], { queryParamsHandling: "merge" }).then((value) => {
            if (value) {
              this.router.navigate(['./globalassetmanager/main/assets/assetfamilies'],
                { queryParams: { page: "types", id: this.params.id, name: this.params.name, assetid: data } });
            }
          });
```

but when i am refreshing components are not rendering properly.i mean some other components are rendering.
kindly let me know how to resolve it.

see the below routing.ts file

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'side', pathMatch: 'prefix', outlet: 'innersidemenu', },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'prefix', },
  {
    path: 'main', component: GlobalAssetManagementComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'assets', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'assets',
        component: GlobalAssetManagementPageContentComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'views', pathMatch: 'prefix', },
          { path: 'views', component: GlobalAssetViewsComponent},
          { path: 'assetfamilies', component: AssetFamiliesComponent},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },


  {
    path: 'side', component: GlobalAssetManagementSidemenuComponent, outlet: 'innersidemenu',
    children: [
      // { path: '', outlet: 'cntsidemenu', component: AssetManagementComponent },
      // { path: '', component: AssetManagementComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'assets', pathMatch: 'prefix', },
      { path: 'assets', component: GlobalAssetManagementSidemenuComponent },
      // { path: 'families', component: AssetFamiliesSidemenuComponent}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class GlobalAssetManagementRoutingModule { }
```

Below is the initial route

```
http://localhost:4200/blm/globalassetmanager/(main/assets/views//innersidemenu:side/assets)?page=libraries&id=118&name=Test%20Library
```

Below is second route(navigating to below route using event)

```
http://localhost:4200/blm/globalassetmanager/(main/assets/assetfamilies//innersidemenu:side/assets)?page=types&id=118&name=Test%20Library&assetid=23f1506c-606d-440b-a777-14dc5d8bea70
```

if i refresh above route is updating as below

```
http://localhost:4200/blm/globalassetmanager/(main/assets/assetfamilies//innersidemenu:side/assets)?page=libraries&id=118&name=Test%20Library
```

Comment: You are using `innersidemenu` outlet in both places routes.

Comment: can not understand

Comment: You need to specify all the outlets where you want the navigation to take place including the primary outlet.